# ruby on rails has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am working on a todo list app.so basically i have created the tables,one is
    subtasks,Project and the join table is assigns.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :name,presence: :true
validates :description,presence: :true
has_many :subtasks,through: :assigns

end
class Subtask < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :projects,through: :assigns

end
class Assign < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :subtask
end
```

with this application i basically want to first create a project.then that project will
    create three tasks namely devlopement,production,testing and with these tasks their wil
    be subtasks,which are the most important ones.so if for a task like devlopement,il have
    todo of "working on jquery error","working on php",such todo's associated with tasks.

```
So,finally now my question is are my associations correct.coz my project should 
definitely have has_many with subtasks,but i think that every subtask belongs
to individual projects and diff projects will have diff subtasks.  

Please suggest me any changes if i am goin wrong sumwhere or if my associations 
are incorrect.

i have added the associations now,pls hav a look at it

And this is how the database looks
projects
id    name     description     created_at      updated_at

subtasks
id    name     description     created_at      updated_at

assigns
id    project_id    task_id  taskname created_at   updated_at
```

Comment: You've not detailed your associations, just your database schemas :)

Comment: i tried doing that but here i was gettig some sort of error saying that my description has mainly the code and no text.

Comment: here are the associations:class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :name,presence: :true
 validates :description,presence: :true
 has_many :subtasks,through: :assigns

end/*for subtasks*/class Subtask < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :projects,through: :assigns
 
end/*for assigns*/class Assign < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :subtask
end

Comment: what does task_id is doing there

Comment: c basically i need a way to store the task names,like devlopement,production,testing,and then these will be associated with subtasks,so task_id is used to map it to a associated subtask

Comment: so it should be subtask_id not task_id

Comment: NitinJ,yes i understood that thing,but then c i need to store the task name as well,so for example,first i create a project say "My project",then in that i want to create several task,one for example be say "Devlopement",now inside that devlopment task their will be all the todo's or subtasks that i want,so i need to associate a task with several subtasks and also with project.

Comment: one more thing class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :name,presence: :true
validates :description,presence: :true
has_many :subtasks,through: :assigns
end coming twice in the question

Comment: Sorry,that was by mistake,i have corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from what you've written, I'd look at this:

---

**Models**

```
#app/models/project.rb
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tasks
    has_many :subtasks, through: :tasks

    after_create :add_tasks

    private
    def add_tasks
        tasks.create(name: "Production")
        tasks.create(name: "Development")
        tasks.create(name: "Test")
    end 
end

#app/models/task.rb
Class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :subtask
end

#app/models/subtask.rb
Class SubTask < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tasks
    has_many :projects, through: :tasks
end
```

This will create a set of `tasks` each time you `create` a new `Project`. This means you can then allocate `subtasks` to each task using the `has_many :through` association (using `Task` as a join model)

---

**Schemas**

```
projects
id    name  description     created_at      updated_at

tasks
id    project_id    subtask_id  created_at updated_at

subtasks
id    name  description  created_at   updated_at
```

This could by DRYed up massively by making the `Tasks` constant somehow. I would have to think about how to do this (probably using system-wide config vars using a gem like [ConfigSpartan](https://github.com/cjbottaro/config_spartan))

---

**[has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)**

I think you're getting confused about how you can access the correct data. I'll do my best to explain how it works for you!

When you want to have a "child" model, you'll have to use a `has_many :through` relationship to give you the ability to create a `many_to_many` association. This will mean you can call your data like this:

```
#app/models/project.rb
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :production, -> { joins(:tasks).where("task.name = Production") }
    scope :development, -> { joins(:tasks).where("task.name = Development") } 
    scope :test, -> { joins(:tasks).where("task.name = Test") } 
end

#app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
def show
     @project_production = Project.production.subtasks
     @project_development = Project.development.subtasks
     @project_test = Project.test.subtasks
end

#app/views/projects/show.html.erb
<h2>Production</h2>
<% @project_production.each do |subtask| %>
    <%= subtask.name %>
<% end %>

<h2>Development</h2>
<% @project_development.each do |subtask| %>
    <%= subtask.name %>
<% end %>

<h2>Test</h2>
<% @project_test.each do |subtask| %>
    <%= subtask.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rick Peck,it seems that this is sumwhat i was looking for,but i will need some time to understnd ur code,since i am just a newbie in rails,Learnin it by devloping an app.

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you have any questions :) The scopes can be DRYed up, but I figured it might help spark some ideas

Comment: Rich Peck,in the class project,dont u think it should be self.tasks.build,instead of self.tasks.projects.build,can u clear this doubt

Comment: My mistake (sorry)! I have fixed for you :)

Comment: your code worked perfectly for me.Thanks again.I was now trying to add a new task,but getting an error saying cant find project without an id,.what i am doin is that on the show page where i am showing all the tasks,i have added a link to create new task,which takes me to tasks/new,,so thats why its not able to build a task associated with the project,since the project id is not beind passed.ny suggestions on that

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake -- we should have used `after_create` in the model callback, not `before_create`, this would happen without the `Project` object being saved. I've updated for you!

Comment: alright,that wasnt much of a problem,though,i am facing difficult right now in adding a new task,to the existing project,like production,developement,nd testing were by default created,now i want to add more

Comment: New task or new `sub_task`?

Comment: new task i want to add but to the existing project

Comment: i created a new task controller for that,it has the new action,but in facing problem in associting that new task with the already existing project

Comment: You've got an [antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) going on here bud - You're trying to create a new task, when it's subtask you want to create

Comment: I kind of thought this when was writing my answer - I'm guessing you need to use an extra model to manage the category of the task. So instead of having `production` / `development` / `test` in your `tasks` db, you'd have them in a `category` db, and then tasks will be added to the `tasks` db directly. I can amend the answer if you want?

Comment: i figured out another way to do it and its working right now,i basically made task as a nested resource of project,that way i gt the project id

Comment: That's right! But you still have an antipattern - you're using the Tasks DB as a categories DB & a place to store tasks. I was under the impression that you wanted to have subtasks of `Production`, `Development` & `Test`

Comment: i want the tasks and then those tasks will have sub-tasks added to them

Comment: "with this application i basically want to first create a project.then that project will
create three tasks namely devlopement,production,testing"

Comment: Is this what you want, or would you prefer to have `tasks` as an manually-inputted record, with `sub_tasks` as stories associated with those tasks?

Comment: yes i am sorry,i should have mentioned it properly,but i thgt if some how those three primary tasks will get created,then i l b able to figure out how to add the rest.

Comment: i want those to be created always as the default when ever some one creates a new project,then later on if they want they can rename them or add new,which is working in the code right now,with ur help

Comment: Well that generally is the case :) I'll amend my code for you in a minute. Basically, you just need to have a `category` db - which will allow you to allocate tasks to a specific category

Comment: is that category table that ur talkin abt necessary,coz i hav a gt a field in the join table task which stores the name of the task,in other words the category name

Comment: The category is not necessary at all! The way you asked the question will not require a category db; but as you want to add tasks to the tasks DB, you need to associate each task to a `category`, right?

Comment: i dont think so,i might be wrong,but i am nywhich ways adding the task info to the task database,i just require its name and id to map it to the subtask,which in ur words becomes my categort,The task name is the category

Comment: nd listen,i was now trying to add the subtasks to the task,so i noticed that the task model should have has_many with subtasks right,but the subtask will belong_to only one task.am i correct??

Comment: Subtasks should have `belongs_to`, yes. It seems I missed that part out. What else were you asking, I didn't quite understand?

Comment: c after goin thrugh the code again,i think it requires few changes.So this is wat i think r the changes that r required.firstly, task join table should have has_many association with the subtask tables

Comment: wat relation should the project table have with the subtasks??

Comment: Not according to your specs - you wanted to have a `tasks` table which stored `production` `development` and `testing` values for each `project`. This would require it to be a join model. However, if you want to change the scope & have it as a store for `tasks` (associated to a `category`), you'd want to introduce a category table

Comment: It entirely depends on what you want to put in the tasks table. If you want to populate with your own data, it will be a single `has_many`, but you didn't specify that in the original question

Comment: c the app has to first create a project with the three default tasks.Once thats done,the user has the power to add some new task of his own.Then once dats done,he can add several subtasks to the task,for which we hav the subtask database.so in short the task join table is only required coz i wanted to do a mapping between projects,tasks nd subtasks and also to store the task names

Answer (score 0):

here according this line of code

```
 assigns
id    project_id    task_id  taskname created_at   updated_at
```

seen you make has and belongs to many association but this is not possible because in has and belongs to many association you can't add `taskname created_at   updated_at id` cols there is a limitation of has and belongs to many so if you want to use that fields that create `has_many through association`

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a crucial has_many association here.
you need to add one more line in both `Project` and `SubTask` models, 
`has_many :assigns`

So your `Project` Model should look like

```
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assigns
    has_many :subtasks, through: :assigns
end
```

Same goes for `SubTask` model

Comment: Thanks you Vijayanand,but i have modified the entire thing,nd it seems to be working perfecty as of now.Its according to the code of Rick peck,which he has given in his previous comments.